# Why I am getting an error to initialize letter and how do I fix it?

Tags: java

```
public static char determineGrade(float grade)
{
    char letter;


        if(grade>=90 && grade<=100)
        {
            letter='A';
        }
        else if(grade>=80 && grade<=89)
        {
            letter='B';
        }
        else if(grade>=70 && grade<=79)
        {
            letter='C';
        }
        else if(grade>=60 && grade<=79)
        {
            letter='D';
        }
        else if(grade<=59)
        {
            letter='F';
        }


   return letter;         
}
```

The program keeps telling me to initialize letter but I do not understand why I need to. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if `grade > 100`? *You* may know that that can't happen, but the compiler doesn't. Methods *must* return something, and here there is a way for the method to not return something.

Comment: Compiler does not know that `100` is the highest grade.  Just initialize when you define the variable: `char letter = '':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is :

```
else if(grade<=59)
        {
            letter='F';
        }
```

Should be

```
 else 
        {
            letter='F';
        }
```

Because you have a series of if condition, so the compiler cannot know that whether a condition will be true in run time. So either you need to declare a default value for `letter` or the last `else` should not have any condition.

For grade over 100, there should be some check to handle this.

if grade over 100 is not acceptable, an exception should be thrown at the beginning of the method (as rule of thumb):

```
if(grade > 100){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input"):
}
```

Comment: So a grade over `100` would be an `F`?

Comment: @AstroCB The problem of compiler is it need to make sure there should be a value for `letter`. The logic is not necessary, it is the OP's problem

Comment: I understand the problem; I was just pointing out the issue with the logic of your answer in the context of the question. A more appropriate answer would also point out that you should change the first statement in the `if/else` chain to read `if(grade >= 90)`.

Comment: @AstroCB ha ha, the logic is there is no grade over 100, and if there is, an exception should be thrown, instead of return any value.

Comment: @AstroCB hmm, so this is totally depends on the OP's problem right ? :)

Comment: Sorry; I don't mean to banter, I'm just saying that when the context of the question is obvious, a good answer should also address its logic.

Answer (score 4):

> Why I am getting an error to initialize letter and how do I fix it?

The problem is that it is possible to reach the `return` statement without a value having been assigned to `letter`.  (This happens when `grade` is greater than 100.0.  While that might not make sense in the context of your application, the Java compiler cannot know that.)

People have suggested returning a "default" value.  I think that is wrong, unless the API spec defines a default value.  (And, IMO, it is bad API design to do that.)

I think that a better approach is to throw an exception (for example `IllegalArgumentException`) if the argument provided makes no sense.

```
public static char determineGrade(float grade) {
    if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
        return 'A';
    } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
        return 'B';
    } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
        return 'C';
    } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 79) {
        return 'D';
    } else if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 59) {
        return 'F';
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("grade is out of range: " + grade);
    }
}
```

The other design issue here is whether it is appropriate to use floating point numbers to represent grades.  There is a risk that the computation that calculates the grades gives values that are a tiny bit "off" due to rounding error; i.e. `89.999998` instead of `90.0`.  If you are going to use a floating point type here, you need to use threshold comparisons rather than simple `>=` and `<=` against an integer value.

Comment: IMO, all exceptional cases need to be throw at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @PhamTrung - Declaring unchecked exceptions is optional.

Answer (score 1):

`char letter` simply declares a variable of type `char`. Initialising means assigning it an initial value, before the variable is acted upon elsewhere in the program.

In your case, if `grade` is not in any of the ranges that you explicitly check for, `letter` needs a default value that your method can return. Since this is a local variable in your method, compiler will not assign the standard default value for `char`, as mentioned in this excerpt from the documentation:

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

That is why you need to explicitly initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static char determineGrade(float grade) {
    char letter = 0;

    if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
        letter = 'A';
    } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
        letter = 'B';
    } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
        letter = 'C';
    } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 79) {
        letter = 'D';
    } else if (grade <= 59) {
        letter = 'F';
    }
    return letter;
}
```

there is a situation where all if statements are not executing (when number >100 ). Then letter variable doesn't have a value.To prevent that the letter variable should be initialized with a default value.

Comment: @AstroCB - oh yes it is.  Or more precisely, the literal `0` can be assigned to a `char`.

Comment: @StephenC Interesting; I didn't know that.

Comment: This happens due to the scope of ht vsriable, As letter is a local variable,(not an attribute) the compiler doesn't assign a default value for it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `char` is only given values in `if` statements the method does not know if it will ever be given a value (it assumes there is a chance that none of `if` statements will have a true condition) and therefore you are requested to give an initial value. 
Another way around it would be by turning the last `else if` statement to just an `else` because it covers all if the remaining possibilities anyway.